# Show what edge taken in MultiGraph

Tags: python, networkx

I want to see what edge was taken in the shortest path so I know if it went across the blue wire or the red wire. Below is an example of what I have implemented at a larger scale. I know that it will be going across the 'Red' wire here, but I want to see it when I do nx.shortest_path.

Anyway to see this? Blow is my code

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_node("A")
G.add_node("B")
G.add_edge("A","B",weight=10,wire='Red')
G.add_edge("A","B",weight=12,wire='Blue')
G.add_edge("C","B",weight=3)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos)

plt.show()

nx.shortest_path(G,'A','C')
```

Ideally I want this to scale. Right now I have an implementation that compares to weighted graphs with the same underlying graph, but all nodes only have one edge between them. I swap a weight on one edge, then I output all the paths that are changed between the original and new graphs.

I want to be able to add in multiple edges between nodes, change a weight, and see if from node B->C it took a Blue or Red wire.

Comment: do you want to undestand what edge would be selected as shortest?

Comment: Yea, I want to be able to print out the edges that it would have taken on it's path from one node to another node.

Answer (score 0):

I do like this

```
h = G.subgraph(nx.shortest_path(G,'A','C'))
h.edges(data=True)
[('B', 'C', {'weight': 3}),
 ('B', 'A', {'weight': 10, 'wire': 'Red'}),
 ('B', 'A', {'weight': 12, 'wire': 'Blue'})]

edge_color = nx.get_node_attributes(h,'wire') 
nx.draw_networkx(h, edge_color=[d['wire'] for _,_, d in h.edges(data=True)])
plt.show()
```

[image]

I get 'blue' but I think this so because 'blue' was the second and 'on top of red'. If you add first blue you get red

Comment: Yea, the visual for the graph right now is on the back burner until I get the output of `nx.shortest_path` working how I want. I think I'm going to use `nx.write_dot(G)` eventually to display both edges.

Comment: you can use weight as the thickness of the lines then a thicker line will be visible along with a thin